# bash: storing size of directory to a var

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to store the size of a directory to a variable

```
size=$(du foo_bar) | awk '{print $1}';
echo $size
```

Produces a blank output. Whats wrong with above lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis was incorrect. The following works

```
size=$(du foo_bar | awk '{print $1}');
echo $size
```

Comment: BTW: did you mean `du -s foo_bar`? `du foo_bar` will give you one line for every subdirectory.